# Binary tree node with pointer to siblings in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of the typical `setSibling` C code exercise:

```c
// Assume the tree is fully balanced, i.e. the lowest level is fully populated.
struct Node {
   Node * left;
   Node * right;
   Node * sibling;
}

void setSibling(Node * root) {
   if (!root) return;
   if (root->left) {
      root->left->sibling = root->right;
      if (root->sibling) root->right->sibling = root->sibling->left;
      SetSibling(left);
      SetSibling(right);
   }
}
```

Of course Rust is a different world, so I am forced to think about ownership now. My lousy attempt.

```rust
struct TreeNode<'a> {
    left: Option<&'a TreeNode<'a>>,
    right: Option<&'a TreeNode<'a>>,
    sibling: Option<&'a TreeNode<'a>>,
    value: String
}

fn BuildTreeNode<'a>(aLeft: Option<&'a TreeNode<'a>>, aRight: Option<&'a TreeNode<'a>>, aValue: String) -> TreeNode<'a> {
    TreeNode {
        left: aLeft,
        right: aRight,
        value: aValue,
        sibling: None
    }
}

fn SetSibling(node: &mut Option<&TreeNode>) {
    match node {
        Some(mut n) => {
            match n.left {
                Some(mut c) => {
                    //c*.sibling = n.right;
                    match n.sibling {
                        Some(s) => { n.right.unwrap().sibling = s.left },
                        None => {}
                    }
                },
                None => {}
            }
        },
        None => return
    }
}
```

What's the canonical way to represent graph nodes like these?

Comment: Found this: https://medium.com/@michealkeines/right-sibling-tree-rust-11920d79e601
but still the generic question stands IMHO.

Comment: Recursive references are impossible in Rust :) (or at least: not useful, because it would cause major problems when handling the objects like complete immovability and immutability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: what's the canonical way to represent graph nodes like these?

It seems like a typical case of "confused ownership" once you introduce the sibling link: with a strict tree you can have each parent own its children, but the sibling link means this is a graph, and a given node has multiple owners.

AFAIK there are two main ways to resolve this, at least in safe Rust

- reference counting and inner mutability, if each node is reference-counted, the sibling link can be a reference or weak reference with little trouble, the main drawbacks are this requires inner mutability and the navigation is *gnarly*, though a few utility methods can help
- "unfold" the graph into an array, and use indices for your indirection through the tree, the main drawback is this requires either threading or keeping a backreference (with inner mutability) to the array, or alternatively doing everything iteratively

Both basically work around the ownership constraint, one by muddying the ownership itself, and the other by moving ownership to a higher power (the array).

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68d092d0d86dc32fe07902c832262ef4 seems to be more or less what you're looking using Rc & inner mutability:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    left: Option<Rc<TreeNode>>,
    right: Option<Rc<TreeNode>>,
    sibling: RefCell<Option<Weak<TreeNode>>>,
    v: u8,
}

impl TreeNode {
    pub fn new(v: u8) -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new(TreeNode {
            v,
            ..TreeNode::default()
        })
    }
    pub fn new_with(left: Option<Rc<TreeNode>>, right: Option<Rc<TreeNode>>, v: u8) -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new(TreeNode {
            left,
            right,
            v,
            sibling: RefCell::new(None),
        })
    }
    pub fn set_siblings(self: &Rc<Self>) {
        let Some(left) = self.left() else { return };
        let right = self.right();

        left.sibling.replace(right.map(Rc::downgrade));

        if let Some(sibling) = self.sibling() {
            // not sure this is correct, depending on construction, with
            // 3  5
            //  \  \
            //  2  4
            //   \/
            //   1
            // (2) has a sibling (4) but doesn't have a right node, so 
            // unconditionally setting right.sibling doesn't seem correct
            right
                .unwrap()
                .sibling
                .replace(sibling.left().map(Rc::downgrade));
        }

        left.set_siblings();
        right.map(|r| r.set_siblings());
    }

    pub fn left(&self) -> Option<&Rc<Self>> {
        self.left.as_ref()
    }
    pub fn right(&self) -> Option<&Rc<Self>> {
        self.right.as_ref()
    }
    pub fn sibling(&self) -> Option<Rc<Self>> {
        self.sibling.borrow().as_ref()?.upgrade()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = TreeNode::new_with(
        TreeNode::new_with(TreeNode::new(1).into(), TreeNode::new(2).into(), 3).into(),
        TreeNode::new(4).into(),
        5,
    );
    t.set_siblings();

    assert_eq!(t.left().and_then(|l| l.sibling()).unwrap().v, 4);
    let ll = t.left().and_then(|l| l.left());
    assert_eq!(ll.map(|ll| ll.v), Some(1));
    ll.unwrap().sibling().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(
        t.left()
            .and_then(|l| l.left())
            .and_then(|ll| ll.sibling())
            .unwrap()
            .v,
        2
    );
}
```

Note that I assumed the tree is immutable once created, only the siblings links have to be generated post-facto. So I only added inner mutability for those. I also used weak pointers which probably isn't necessary, if the tree is put in an inconsistent state it's not like that'll save anything. All it requires is a few `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` calls in stead of `clone()` though so it's not a huge imposition.

That aside, there are lots of issues with your attempt:

- having the same lifetime for your reference and your content is usually an error, the compiler *will* trust what you tell it, and that can have rather odd effects (e.g. of telling the compiler that something gets borrowed forever)
- SetSibling (incorrect naming conventions btw) taking an `Option` is... unnecessary, function clearly expects to *set a sibling*, just give it a sibling, and remove the unnecessary outer layer of tests
- `match` is nice, when you need it. Here, you probably don't, `if let` would do the trick fine especially since there is no `else` branch
- rust generally uses methods, and the method to create an instance (if one such is needed) is idiomatically called `new` (if there's only one)

Comment: I guess if we tell this to questions I also have to tell it to answers :) please don't post code as links.

Comment: I don't mind adding the code to the answer, but it's somewhat ancillary and north of 80 LOCs seemed a bit large so I avoided it. Though I guess SO does put scrollbars on the code blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if having an hybrid of strong and weak references was an option, vs using Rcs.